# Set selection to view box

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

Hello I have some buttons randomly assigned in my WPF application like so:

```
partial class Window1
{

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("action 3");
    }
    void button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("action 2");
    }
    void button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("action 1");
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        populateButtons();
    }

    public void populateButtons()
    {
        double xPos;
        double yPos;


        Random ranNum = new Random();
        foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })
        {

            Button foo = new Button();


            Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;
            int sizeValue = 100;

            foo.Width = sizeValue;
            foo.Height = sizeValue;

            xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
            yPos = ranNum.Next(250);


            foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            foo.Style = buttonStyle;

            foo.Click += routedEventHandler;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I set the area in which to populate the buttons like so:

```
        int xPos;
        int yPos;

            xPos = ranNum.Next(239);
            yPos = ranNum.Next(307);


            foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
```

What I would prefer to do now is set this area with a view box named viewbox1 (original eh!) ;)

Is there a way to do this in the code behind?

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xml:lang="en-US"
    x:Class="DynamicButtons.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Dynamic Buttons"
    WindowState="Normal" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
    Width="840" Height="600" Icon="shape_group.png">
    <Window.Resources>   
            <Style x:Key="CurvedButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseMove1">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="#7CE1DBDB"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.66"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.66"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="1.78"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="1.78"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="#BFA0D1E2"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" Fill="#3FFFFFFF" Stroke="{x:Null}" RadiusX="11" RadiusY="11" x:Name="rectangle">
                                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnClick1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseLeave1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseMove1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseMove1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#E1CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
    </Window.Triggers>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid Name="MainLayoutGrid" Background="#2b2b2b">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="4" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="TitleGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0"  Name="ImageIcon" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Name="Titleblk" Foreground="White">Wanna be Title</TextBlock>

                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Name="btnMin" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="8,4,42,-4">
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"></ScaleTransform>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="1000" RadiusY="1000" Rect="0,0,18,20" />
                        </Button.Clip>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Name="btnMax" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,4,23,-4">
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"></ScaleTransform>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="1000" RadiusY="1000" Rect="0,0,18,20" />
                        </Button.Clip>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Name="btnClose" Grid.Column="2" Margin="24,0,6,0" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="0" ClickMode="Press" Foreground="#00000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" OpacityMask="#82F8F8F8" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <Button.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="1000" RadiusY="1000" Rect="0,0,20,20" />
                        </Button.Clip>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.484,0.543" StartPoint="0.478,0.009">
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <UniformGrid>
                    <Viewbox Height="364" Name="viewbox1" Width="363" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,0,441,164" />
                </UniformGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Canvas Height="284" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="457,66,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" />-->
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Full Code:

```
namespace DynamicButtons
{
    partial class Window1
    {

        void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent)
            {
                ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
                t.Content = "Something helpful";
                ((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;
                ((Button)sender).Content = "Hello";
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Hello you punk");
        }
        void button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
            //t.Content = "Something helpful";
            //((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;

            //MessageBox.Show("action 2");
        }
        void button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
            //t.Content = "Something helpful";
            //((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;
            ////Button b = new Button();
            //((Button)sender).Content = "Hello";
            ////b.ToolTip = t;

            //MessageBox.Show("action 1");
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            populateButtons();

        }
        public void populateButtons()
        {
            double xPos;
            double yPos;

            UniformGrid grid = new UniformGrid();

            Viewbox viewBox = new Viewbox();
            viewBox.Name = "viewbox1";
            viewBox.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            viewBox.Child = grid;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(viewBox);
            Random ranNum = new Random();
            foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })
            {
                Button foo = new Button();
                Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;
                int sizeValue = 100;

                foo.Width = sizeValue;
                foo.Height = sizeValue;

                xPos = ranNum.Next(100);
                yPos = ranNum.Next(150);


                foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
                foo.Style = buttonStyle;

                foo.Click += routedEventHandler;
                foo.Loaded += routedEventHandler;

                grid.Children.Add(foo);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the buttons to a ViewBox you can just do this:

```
    public void populateButtons()
    {
        double xPos;
        double yPos;

        UniformGrid grid = new UniformGrid();
        viewbox1.Child = grid;

        Random ranNum = new Random();
        foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })
        {
            Button foo = new Button();
            Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;
            int sizeValue = 100;

            foo.Width = sizeValue;
            foo.Height = sizeValue;

            xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
            yPos = ranNum.Next(250);


            foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            foo.Style = buttonStyle;

            foo.Click += routedEventHandler;

            grid.Children.Add(foo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Anurag UniformGrid missing directive? is there a namespace for this?

Comment: You can use Grid too.  I was just happen to be playing around with UniformGrid. It is in System.Windows.Controls.Primitives

Comment: I think its because its not actually telling it to go to viewbox1 maybe because child is used rather than UniformedGrid being the parent of viewbox1 but Parent doesnt work?

Comment: You can set absolute values for `viewBox.Height` and `viewBox.Width` id you don't want to fill the whole window. I have updated the code.

Comment: but viewbox1 is set within my build and its set to stretch in the code so it should only fit inside viewbox1? Which means this code isnt working?

Comment: or should I say its just doing the same as I have set it with x and y cordinates there is no difference

Comment: Can you post the code where you declare viewBox1? And what is a child of?

Comment: updated with both full code behind including your method and xaml code. The viewbox is at the end of the xaml code.

Comment: I thought `viewBox.Name = "viewBox(xaml viewbox name i.e viewbox1);` was what you put here but when loaded all I get is the buttons everywhere rather than in the constraints of the viewbox1.

Comment: God your fast! It now works from your updated code, I thought viewBox.Name was telling it the name in the xaml, but it all works now! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

What is your reasoning for using a Viewbox?  Is it for stretch and scale reasons?

I recommend using a Canvas and then you can set your Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top values similarly to how you set xPos and yPos.

Then if you wish to have the stretch / scale features of the Viewbox, you could put the Canvas you created as the child of the Viewbox.

UPDATE: to get the ActualHeight and ActualWidth values of the canvas during runtime you can add an event handler for SizeChanged (easy to do within the XAML but not too hard within code) to handle the change in height/width value during runtime.   Here's the code solution:

```
bool initialized = false;  // Should be located in class definition for your window
                           // ex. within "public partial class WindowName : Window
canvas.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(canvas_SizeChanged);
                          // Can be located in constructor for window 
                          // ie. public MainWindow() { /* put it right here */ }
```

then the definition for the event handler can be as follows:  (this only creates one button but would work with your for loop.)

*Location update* This definition below can be located within the class def for your window, but below the definition for the boolean variable "initialized".  (ex. w/in "public partial class WindowName : Window")

```
     private void canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
            {
            if (initialized == false)  // so this only happens once.
             {
                 int sizeValue = 100;
                 Random ranNum = new Random();
                 int modHeight = System.Convert.ToInt32(canvas.ActualHeight)-sizeValue;
                 int modWidth = System.Convert.ToInt32(canvas.ActualWidth)-sizeValue;
                 Button foo = new Button();
                 canvas.Children.Add(foo);
                 foo.Width = sizeValue;
                 foo.Height = sizeValue;
                 xPos = ranNum.Next(239) % modWidth;
                 yPos = ranNum.Next(307) % modHeight
                 Canvas.SetLeft(foo, xPos);
                 Canvas.SetTop(foo, yPos);
                 initialized = true;
            }
}
```

Or, if you know what size your canvas is going to be you can just manually set modHeight and modWidth to the pixel value of your choice and not have to deal with the event handler.

Comment: ahhh! Yes it was for those reasons viewbox isnt esential

Comment: The thing is foo is a button xpos and ypos only react to the windows for y,x positions I cant contain them within the canvas?

Comment: `double canvasWidth = canvas1.Height;
                double canvasHeight = canvas1.Width;
                xPos = ranNum.Next(200) % canvasWidth;
                yPos = ranNum.Next(250) % canvasHeight;` if I try this nothing happens still staying in the same place

Comment: Just updated my answer - made it more complicated since a canvas's width and height values are irrelevant / not a number until they are changed during runtime.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear.  Added some comments that should help with where to put everything.

Comment: Can you see my code? Notice how I populate buttons on initialization this method doesnt do anything?